# Amazon SNS topic subscription confirmation for mobile apps

Tags: amazon-web-services, publish-subscribe, amazon-sns

I'd like to understand how amazon SNS confirms endpoint subscription in case of mobile apps.
For SMS, HTTP or email enpoints, we can assume a confirmation SMS, call and email is sent.

But for apps, SNS seems to be managing all notifications through third party services like GCM, APNS etc.
Say I have a GCM client and server ready.
My client wants to subscribe to a topic. How is the confirmation message sent to the device?

Answer (score 4):

Amazon SNS auto-confirms mobile endpoints like GCM, APNs etc. From the [Amazon SNS FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/),

> Q: Does enabling push notifications require any special confirmations
>   with SNS Mobile Push?
>
> No, they do not. End-users opt-in to receive push notifications when
>   they first run an app, whether or not SNS delivers the push
>   notifications.

Comment: I am looking for information on topic subscription confirmation. This is a one-time confirmation when the app is installed. What happens when the user subscribes to a topic? Is a confirmation sent in that case?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "What happens when the user subscribes to a topic?"

Comment: I guess a better way to put it would be " What happens when an app;lication end point is registered to a topic", as described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send-topicmobile.html. The link asks to follow the same steps as http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SubscribeTopic.html but doesnt talk about how the confirmation happens in case of an application.

Comment: There is no confirmation required for endpoints of mobile applications when they are subscribed to topics. This is called out in the FAQ link that I provided. You should be able to test this very quickly with the SNS console.